# centos Artifactory tomcat set port to 80

Tags: tomcat, centos, artifactory

i'm install artifactory RPM 4.5.2 on CentOS 6.7

it have inculd tomcat and default port is "8081"

and I want to set tomact port "8081" to "80"。

But, after I changed and start it, the screen show

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED。

and tomact log like this :

```
11-Mar-2016 17:16:07.483 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"] java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

How can I fix it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports below 1024 on Linux are privileged and only the root user can open listening sockets on them.  You'll need to set up an HTTP proxy server if you want to access Artifactory on port 80.  Artifactory will generate the proxy configuration for nginx or Apache - see the [documentation here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy).

Comment: but, I am login as root it still cant use port80 . even I close the iptables or registered 80 port in iptable setting